# Cakephp: setting values to $this->data in controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to set values in $this->data which is received in controller from the view.

We can use if($this->data['id']) but why we cant set values in it?

Will this work`$this->data['id']=$userid;`

Comment: Because, usually, `$this->data['id']` will not be set.. You'd expect a userid in `$this->data['User']['id']`. Try using `die(print_r($this->data))` to see what your data array looks like, and as I suggested before, please read the CakePHP Cookbook as found on http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/876/The-Manual . Read it from front to end (or at least chapters 1, 2 and 3) and a lot will be clarified.

Comment: I have to save some data. `$this->Post->save($this->data)`. There is data in `$this->data`. Before it is saved i want to modify user_id in $this->data.

Comment: You'll have to post up more of what you're trying to accomplish. Post your form, post which Model this concerns, and please post a print_r of what your $this->data looks like. And add the relevant controller code as well, please

Answer (score 7):

You have a couple of options

The first is to just create your own variable and modify that:

```
$myData = $this->data;
$myData['id'] = $userid;
$this->Post->save($myData);
```

The second is to use $this->request->data. It contains the same info as $this->data but can be modified.

```
$this->request->data['id'] = $userid;
$this->Post->save($this->request->data);
```

Comment: The question I asked was not interpreted as i expected.
I was getting some data in 
`$this->data`

I wanted to modify a field users_id(Foreign key) in it with the current user's user id which didnt had any value in it.

I tried to do this `$this->data['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');` but it didnt work.

$this->Auth->user('id') returns current users id.

So another way to do what i wanted to is 

`$this->CurrentModel->set('user_id', $this->Auth->user('id'));`
 
`$this->CurrentModel->save($this->data);`

Comment: careful - he seems to be using 1.3 (from the tags) - so it would $this->data (no request object yet)!

Comment: @Alan Wagstaff: AFAIK you _can_ edit the data in $this->data.